# Nginx password protect

Tags: nginx

I need to password protect my folder using nginx.

I've used this rule

```
    location ^~ /test/
    {
            auth_basic            "Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file  conf/htpasswd;
    }
```

But the problme is that if i go to /test/file.php it works, it does not requires authorization.
Only /test/ asks for a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using it like this:

```
        location ~ /img/index.php {
        root   /var/www/nginx-default/phpmyedit/;
        auth_basic "phpmyedit";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/phpmyedit.pass;
        access_log   /var/log/nginx/img.log;
         fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/nginx-default$fastcgi_script_name;
         include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set up the passwords correctly all you need to do is remove the trailing slash in your path. Also, you don't need the ^~ in the rule. Here's an example:

```
         location /test {
             try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
             auth_basic "Access Denied!";
             auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
         }
```

To add new users to the password use the following steps:

```
sudo sh -c "echo -n 'admin:' >> /etc/nginx/.htpasswd"
```

This will add a new user: admin to the file. To set the encrypted password for this new user use:

```
sudo sh -c "openssl passwd -apr1 >> /etc/nginx/.htpasswd"
```

You will be prompted to enter the password and verify the new password. That's it. You are all set!